# Cannot explain behaviour of copyOfRange(int[] a, int from, int to) function

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I was trying to do some slice copy using Arrays static function copyOfRegion. My code is given below:

```
public class MyJavaArrays {
    static int[] findEquilibPoint(int[] A) {

        int[] resArray = {-1};
        /* 
         * Our equilibrium condition is that the index must be between 0 and length
         * of the input array
         *
         */
         int l = A.length;
         int sum_l = 0;
         int sum_r = 0;
         int j = 0;
         for(int i=1; i<l-1; i++) {
            sum_l=0;
            sum_r=0;

            int[] b1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A,0,i-1);
            int[] b2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(A,i+1,l-1);
            System.out.println("START HERE..............\n");
            for (int s: b1)
                System.out.print(s + ", ");
            System.out.println("\n............");
            for (int s: b2)
                System.out.print(s + ", ");
            System.out.println("\n............");
            for (int x: b1){sum_l += x;}
            for (int y: b2){sum_r += y;}
            System.out.println(sum_l+" ?= "+sum_r);
            /* if the sums are equal, we have an equilibrium point */
            if (sum_l == sum_r) {
            resArray[j] = i;
            j++;
            }
         }
         return resArray;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] A = {-1, 3, -4, 5, 1,-6, 2, 1};
        findEquilibPoint(A);        

    }
```

I tried to run it using different limits for `i` (l-1, l, l+1) and my investigation reveals that copyOfRange() method is actually doing `to-1`. My output for the code above is given below:

```
START HERE..............


............
-4, 5, 1, -6, 2, 
............
0 ?= -2
START HERE..............

-1, 
............
5, 1, -6, 2, 
............
-1 ?= 2
START HERE..............

-1, 3, 
............
1, -6, 2, 
............
2 ?= -3
START HERE..............

-1, 3, -4, 
............
-6, 2, 
............
-2 ?= -4
START HERE..............

-1, 3, -4, 5, 
............
2, 
............
3 ?= 2
START HERE..............

-1, 3, -4, 5, 1, 
............

............
4 ?= 0
```

I can clearly see that after the first "START HERE............" statement, there is nothing! I am a bit puzzled, but is this any known bug? I also went to [Tutorialspoint website](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_copyofrange_int.htm) to check if my understanding of copyOfRange was wrong. But it seems the chap is doing what I want to do.

Any ideas/suggestion anybody?

Comment: that's what `to - the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive.` means.

Comment: you want to use `(A,0,i)` and `(A,i,l-1)`

Comment: in java, most array-related indexes define semi-open ranges. The start index is usually inclusive, the end index is usually exclusive, which gives `length = end - start`, which is convenient.

Comment: @njzk2          but I am still not getting anything right! the idea is to find the point where the array is in equillibrium i.e. the sum of elms before and after that will be the same.

Comment: there is no such point in you array, unless you intend on excluding the element A[i], in which case `(A,i+1,l)` instead of `(A,i,l)` should do.